# Why am I getting weird output when running my script from the terminal, and is it ok to ignore?

Tags: python, terminal, pycharm, selenium-chromedriver

I have a Python Selenium Chromedriver Script that runs as expected when I click the play button on Pycharm.  It logs in and scrapes a job board and automatically applies, refreshes the page, or sleeps, depending on conditions, as well as outputs what it's doing to console.  However, when I run it from the command prompt or another terminal, I get the following strange output:

```
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:53588/devtools/browser/f1585e49-a21a-4191-a5a5-a7359ee08f36
[0114/191014.143:INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "[.WebGL-000005680692D400]GL Driver Message (OpenGL, Performance, GL_CLOSE_PATH_NV, High): GPU stall due to ReadPixels", source: https://www.wyzant.com/login (0)
[0114/191015.857:INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "[.WebGL-0000056806EC4700]GL Driver Message (OpenGL, Performance, GL_CLOSE_PATH_NV, High): GPU stall due to ReadPixels", source: https://www.wyzant.com/tutor/home (0)
refresh 1
[0114/191021.720:INFO:CONSOLE(43710)] "Refused to create a worker from 'blob:https://www.wyzant.com/9c1ad633-bb91-4d3a-99e3-4fb923d719bc' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' http: 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline'". Note that 'worker-src' was not explicitly set, so 'script-src' is used as a fallback.
", source: https://vjs.zencdn.net/7.6.0/video.js (43710)
[0114/191022.742:INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "[.WebGL-000005680692C600]GL Driver Message (OpenGL, Performance, GL_CLOSE_PATH_NV, High): GPU stall due to ReadPixels", source: https://www.wyzant.com/tutor/jobs?action=index&controller=tutor_facing%2Fjobs&page=1 (0)
[0114/191025.707:INFO:CONSOLE(43710)] "Refused to create a worker from 'blob:https://www.wyzant.com/a82c4441-febb-4d5c-9fc7-c82c02a42e6a' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' http: 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline'". Note that 'worker-src' was not explicitly set, so 'script-src' is used as a fallback.
", source: https://vjs.zencdn.net/7.6.0/video.js (43710)
[0114/191026.715:INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "[.WebGL-0000056806EC7800]GL Driver Message (OpenGL, Performance, GL_CLOSE_PATH_NV, High): GPU stall due to ReadPixels (this message will no longer repeat)", source: https://www.wyzant.com/tutor/jobs?action=index&controller=tutor_facing%2Fjobs&page=1 (0)
```

This output repeats itself in between expected output, I assume every time the page refreshes.  The script still does what I want it to, I just get all this extra output that kind of gets in the way.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28282935/working-around-webgl-readpixels-being-slow

Comment: I don't see how that's related besides "WebGL" and "ReadPixels" were mentioned.

Comment: If you are happy with the performance of your application, it's fine. Otherwise see [here](https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase/issues/1384).